# How do you serialize a window-configuration?

Tags: persistence, window-configuration

Suppose I used <kbd>C-x r w</kbd> to run `window-configuration-to-register`, and suppose I saved it to the register `k`.  Later, when I read back the register, I get this.

```lisp
ELISP> (get-register ?k)
(#<window-configuration> #<marker at 5433 in *ielm*>)
```

Is there any way to serialize `#<window-configuration>` such that I could write code that prefills a registers with various window configurations on start up?  I want to be able to use <kbd>C-x r j</kbd> to `jump-to-register` to a few known window configurations.

Comment: The beginnings are described in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual in [Window Configurations](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Configurations.html) which also includes the description of a few functions that  can be used "in order to store a window configuration on disk and read it back in another Emacs session ...", although I suspect there are many details to work out. Looking forward to your answer :-)

Comment: I don't think the question is really about registers. If so, consider removing that tag. I think it's about persisting a window config in a way that it can be reread (loaded) and thus restored from disk. That's independent of using registers.

Comment: NickD - Thanks for the tip.  I was able to figure something out after following that link.
Drew - Focusing on window configs and forgetting about registers was a good call.  It turned out to be easier to solve the higher-level problem without using the existing register infrastructure.
I'll provide a public answer to my own question soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unfortunate thing about the function `window-configuration-to-register` is that it returns an opaque `#<window-configuration>` data structure that is not easily serialized.  Instead, one should use the function `window-state-get` which will return a window configuration as an elisp data structure.  Calling it with the following parameters will return a data structure that is amenable to being saved in an elisp source file.

```lisp
(window-state-get (frame-root-window) t)
```

The return value of the above function can be passed to `window-state-put` to restore the window configuration later.  To make this more generally usable, I came up with the following interactive functions.

```lisp
(defvar w/configs (make-hash-table :test #'equal)
  "This is a hash-table where window configurations used by w/save and w/load are stored.")

(defun w/save (key)
  "Save the current window configuration to w/configs."
  (interactive "sName for window configuration: ")
  (puthash key
           (window-state-get (frame-root-window) t)
           w/configs))

(defun w/load (key)
  "Load a named window configuration from w/configs."
  (interactive
   (let* ((completion-ignore-case t)
          (completions '())
          (nothing (maphash (lambda (k v) (push k completions)) w/configs)))
     (list (completing-read "Choose: " completions nil t))))
  (window-state-put (gethash key w/configs)))
```

These two functions can be used to save and load window configurations into the hash-table `w/configs`.  If there are window configurations you use often, you can preload `w/configs` with those settings.  Binding these functions to keys is left as an exercise for the reader.

This solution doesn't use registers, but that's OK.  It does solve the higher-level problem of saving and loading window configurations in elisp data structures.  Whether the register system is used or a hash-table is used is an implementation detail.