# save a specific layout

Tags: window, window-splitting, persistence, window-configuration

I am pretty new to emacs (doom-emacs in this case) and I have an idea of what I want to do, but not sure how to do it.

What I am after is that when I open a `.js` file, I want to split my window into 3.
one small window on the left where I want to run `jest`, and one small window on the right if there is a test file for the file opened in the buffer (following the format `*.spec.(js|ts)`).

is this doable in emacs or should I just give up on these dreams?

Comment: I have a feeling this question might be a duplicate. Search the tags for this (put a tag in brackets ([]) to search for it). If you find a dup, please delete this one. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible.  Here is my initial attempt at creating the 3 window split with a jest test runner, a source file, and it's associated spec file.  You can put this code in your config and try it out via <kbd>M-x jest-open</kbd>.

```lisp
(defun jest-spec-for-file (file)
  "Given a file, return its matching spec file."
  (let* ((dirname  (file-name-directory    file))
         (filename (file-name-nondirectory file))
         (ext      (file-name-extension    file))
         (basename
          (replace-regexp-in-string (concat "." ext "$") "" filename)))
    (concat dirname basename ".spec." ext)))

(defvar jest-command "jest --watch"
  "This is the shell command used to run jest.")

(defun jest-run (&optional term)
  "Switch to the jest buffer if it exists or create a new one."
  (interactive)
  (if (get-buffer "jest") (switch-to-buffer "jest")
    (cond ((equal term 'vterm)
           (progn
             (vterm "jest")
             (vterm-send-string (concat jest-command "\n"))))
           (t
            (progn
             (term "/bin/bash")
             (rename-buffer "jest")
             (term-send-raw-string (concat jest-command "\n"))
             ))
           )))

(defun jest-open (file)
  "Create a 3 window layout containing jest|source|spec."
  (interactive "f")
  (let* ((spec (jest-spec-for-file file)))
    (delete-other-windows)
    (split-window-right)
    (split-window-right)
    (jest-run)             ; change this to (jest-run 'vterm)
    (windmove-right)
    (find-file file)
    (windmove-right)
    (find-file spec)
    (windmove-left)))
```

## How It Works

We have 3 functions and a variable.

#### (jest-spec-for-file *file*)

Return the spec file associated with `file`.
This is just pure string manipulation that takes a string like `/tmp/index.js` and returns `/tmp/index.spec.js`.

#### jest-command

This variable contains the shell command used to invoke jest.  Feel free to adapt it to your needs.

#### (jest-run &optional *term*)

If a buffer named "jest" exists, switch to it.  Otherwise, create a term (or vterm) buffer and run `jest-command` inside of it.  I have it default to use `term` since it's included with stock emacs, but I highly recommend giving **[vterm](https://github.com/akermu/emacs-libvterm)** a try.  Anything that's even slightly animated will look better in vterm.  When you're ready to make the switch, change the line that says:

```lisp
(jest-run)
```

to

```lisp
(jest-run 'vterm)
```

Also, keep in mind that if you hit <kbd>q</kbd> to stop jest, this function won't try to restart it.  Once the jest buffer is created, all control is deferred to you.

#### (jest-open *file*)

Finally, we have the function that creates the 3 window split and sets up the buffers such that you have a jest test runner on the left, the source in the middle, and a spec file on the right.  It will also place the focus on the middle window, because I think that's what would be most intuitive.

You can give it a try by hitting <kbd>M-x jest-open</kbd> and selecting a file when prompted.  If you end up wanting to use this frequently, you can [bind it to a key](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Changing-Key-Bindings).  You can do it the [doom way](https://rameezkhan.me/posts/2020/2020-07-03--adding-keybindings-to-doom-emacs/) too.

## PS

I tried to write this in a way that works in any Emacs configuration.  It should work just fine in Doom.  As you explore this code (or any other elisp), I encourage you to use <kbd>C-h f</kbd> look up the docs for functions.  I also like using <kbd>M-x ielm</kbd> to start up an interactive elisp repl to feel how things work.  Doing this really accelerated my elisp self-education.

Answer (score 0):

Use `M-x window-configuration-to-register` (bound to `C-x r w` in vanilla Emacs, not sure about Doom). From the documentation:

window-configuration-to-register is an interactive and natively
compiled function defined in register.el.gz.

Signature
(window-configuration-to-register REGISTER)

Documentation
Store the window configuration of the selected frame in register REGISTER.

Use C-x r j to restore the configuration.
Argument is a character, naming the register.

Interactively, reads the register using register-read-with-preview.

Comment: The problem I had with `window-configuration-to-register` is that it's really hard to persist the value of a `#<window-configuration>` that's in a register between restarts of emacs.  However, I did come up with an [alternative](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73842/how-do-you-serialize-a-window-configuration/73858#73858).

Comment: You need desktop mode (desktop.el) -- that lets you persist anything you specify.

Comment: I'll look into that.  Thanks.